# CommandButton navigate to named anchor

Tags: jsf

I have a CommandButton on my JSF page. Can I redirect the user to the same JSF page, but with named anchor? Something like that: "../page.jsf#link"

Thanks,
Oles

P.S.: I'm using the JSF 1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use navigation cases for this. You'd need [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void submit() throws IOException {
    // ...

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("page.jsf#link");
}
```

Comment: Has it been any improvement on this in JSF 2.x? It would be nice for navigation cases to accept named anchors.